# How to insert an array in a json object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a string on my databas, that I'm trying to insert into a json object as an Array, not a string..:

```
$arrayInString = "[2,3,5,5,6]"; // this comes from the database
$jsonObject = array('numbers' => $arrayInString);
$json = json_encode($jsonObject, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
echo $json;
```

When I execute this.. my Json object is..

```
numbers: "[2,3,5,5,6]";
```

and not

```
numbers: [2,3,5,5,6];
```

Like I originally wanted.. can't get this to work, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like was said you need to decode the passed data from the database and then build your array output. Something like this:

```
    $arrayInString = "[2,3,5,5,6]"; // this comes from the database

    // decode the JSON from the database as we build the array that will be converted back to json
    $jsonObject = array('numbers' => json_decode($arrayInString));

    echo json_encode($jsonObject, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

The slightly modified code above outputs:

```
{"numbers":[2,3,5,5,6]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to `json_decode` your `$arrayInString` variable before you add it to the associative array.